# How do I install and get HAML working with Yii?

Tags: php, yii, composer-php, haml, yii2

There are many PHP Haml projects and some specifically for Yii. The generic ones I have no idea how to install into the Yii framework and make Yii aware of them. The ones for Yii are for the old Yii and not Yii2 so they make reference to `protected/extensions` which doesn't exist. I tried to install this one https://github.com/delfit/yii-haml but composer gave an error `The requested package delfit/phamlp could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.` SASS and Coffeescript is a bonus [image: smile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you mentioned most likely is related with `minimum-stability` setting because this extension doesn't have any stable releases yet. Also it seems like it's not supported anymore.

But Yii 1 extensions is not compatible with Yii 2, because the difference between them is pretty big, so it doesn't even matter.

You can always rewrite it to newer version, but I actually found similar extension for Yii2.

It's called [yii2-mthaml](https://github.com/mervick/yii2-mthaml) and it based on [mthaml](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml) extension. Try this, seems like it's the only one yii2 haml extension at the moment.